# Ruby on rails array to HTML table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi after I tried a lot of code and read a lot of documentation I have always the same error

> undefined method `each' for `nil`:`NilClass`

My code conttrollers/pages_controller.rb:

```
 class PagesController < ApplicationController

    myarr =  [{ville_id: '1', ville_name: 'Paris', population: 2000000, pays: 'France'},
              {ville_id: '2', ville_name: 'Madrid', population: 3000000, pays: 'Espagne'},
              {ville_id: '3', ville_name: 'Marrakech', population: 1000000, pays: 'Maroc'},
              {ville_id: '4', ville_name: 'Tokyo', population: 9000000, pays: 'Japon'},
              {ville_id: '5', ville_name: 'Istanbul', population: 15000000, pays: 'Turquie'}]

end
```

And my erb html code layouts/pages/listing.html.erb:

```
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ville Id</th>
          <th>Ville</th>
          <th>Population</th>
          <th>Pays</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @myarr.each do |myarr| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= myarr.ville_id %></td>
            <td><%= myarr.ville_name %></td>
            <td><%= myarr.population %></td>
            <td><%= myarr.pays %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add code of view

Comment: show your controller code (at least the listing action), not just the array assignment

Comment: Thaks ! I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use an instance variable outside of the scope of the controller instance. In the way you are using it, you could only declare it as a class variable (i.e. `@@my_arr`), which you probably don't want to do.

Instead, you should wrap the declaration of `@my_arr` in a method:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def listing
    @my_arr = [{ville_id: '1', ville_name: 'Paris', population: 2000000, pays: 'France'},
              {ville_id: '2', ville_name: 'Madrid', population: 3000000, pays: 'Espagne'},
              {ville_id: '3', ville_name: 'Marrakech', population: 1000000, pays: 'Maroc'},
              {ville_id: '4', ville_name: 'Tokyo', population: 9000000, pays: 'Japon'},
              {ville_id: '5', ville_name: 'Istanbul', population: 15000000, pays: 'Turquie'}]
  end

end
```

The method is named `listing` to correspond with the view.

Also, as someone else mentioned, you are creating `Hash` objects, and properties of those objects are accessed via the `[]` method (yes, `[]` is a method!), i.e. `myarr[:ville_id]`, `myarr[:ville_name]`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

`@myarr` is not the same as `myarr`. You must change `myarr = [...]` to `@myarr = [...]`.

Also, if `{ville_id: '1', ville_name: 'Paris', population: 2000000, pays: 'France'}` is `Hash` (not `Class` or `OpenStruct`) update view too:

```
   <% @myarr.each do |myarr| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= myarr[:ville_id] %></td>
        <td><%= myarr[:ville_name] %></td>
        <td><%= myarr[:population] %></td>
        <td><%= myarr[:pays] %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take instance variable `@myarr` instead of only `myarr`
You defined `@myarr` in view which are correct , Change `myarr` to `@myarr` in controller action

Comment: Thank you I changed myarr to @myarr in my controller but i have always the same error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Please add the name of controller  and action. also add the name of view file in question

Comment: Yes :) Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@myarr` only in view and it is not needed in the controller logic, I believe her becomes the role of the *Helpers*, You can simply define a method in a helper (`application_helper.rb` or `page_helper.rb`), I prefer creating a helper for the controller like this:

```
module PageHelper
  def my_list
         [{ville_id: '1', ville_name: 'Paris', population: 2000000, pays: 'France'},
          {ville_id: '2', ville_name: 'Madrid', population: 3000000, pays: 'Espagne'},
          {ville_id: '3', ville_name: 'Marrakech', population: 1000000, pays: 'Maroc'},
          {ville_id: '4', ville_name: 'Tokyo', population: 9000000, pays: 'Japon'},
          {ville_id: '5', ville_name: 'Istanbul', population: 15000000, pays: 'Turquie'}]
  end
end
```

Then this will clear your controller, and in `view` you have to use it like this:

```
<% my_list.each do |myarr| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= myarr.ville_id %></td>
        <td><%= myarr.ville_name %></td>
        <td><%= myarr.population %></td>
        <td><%= myarr.pays %></td>
      </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Of course you can customize `my_list` by giving it params and make it works as you like, I prefer this way, But remember when only this instance variable `@myvar` is only needed in the view layer, Hope this helps.